# Button sound effect only works 28 times

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have set a gunshot sound to play every time I press a button (It is a fire button so it needs to be clicked many times). 
When I run the program, the gunshot sound plays every time I press it, but after the 28th time the button is pressed, the sound is no longer played. However, the `Toast` I added still works. Any idea why this is?

**activity_main.xml:**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/fire"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fire"
        android:onClick="fire"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**Main.java:**

```
package com.example.brans.zoombie;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void fire(View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.pistol);
    mp.start();
    Toast.makeText(this, "shot fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

After the 29th Time, the logcat says this.

```
04-02 16:07:56.371 23703-23717/com.example.brans.zoombie       V/MediaPlayer:message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-19
04-02 16:07:56.371 23703-23717/com.example.brans.zoombie E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
04-02 16:07:56.371 23703-23717/com.example.brans.zoombie V/MediaPlayer: callback application
04-02 16:07:56.371 23703-23717/com.example.brans.zoombie V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
```

Comment: What about a breakpoint which breaks on the 29th to check the state of the different variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove media player from RAM to avoid out of memory exceptions.

```
public void fire(View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.pistol);
    mp.start();
    Toast.makeText(this, "shot fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mp.stop();
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }

      }
    });
}
```

Comment: This code works, the one thing I changed was to make mp `final`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have to release the Media Player to release from the completed sound then reset it to play it another time. so it will no longer in the memory.